# Python (PyCharm) If / Else does not working as the expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
total_cost = 60
if total_cost > 30:
    discount = 0.8
else:
    discount = 2
    total_cost *=discount
print('Tony Pay：{} USD'.format(total_cost))
```

[It's don't working,can't result the true number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxNeg.png)
I want result be the true number----->48
Pls tell me what's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Your ident is too deep on line 6

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
total_cost = 60
if total_cost > 30:
    discount = 0.8
else:
    discount = 2
total_cost *= discount
print('Tony Pay：{} USD'.format(total_cost))
```